# CakePHP 3.0, Production 500 Error caused by Vendor

Tags: php, json, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using CAKEPHP version 3.4.

Here is the error stack-trace from error.log

```
 2017-03-16 21:37:45 Error: [ParseError] syntax error, unexpected 'getWordCount' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in /home/mfeditin/public_html/mf_editing_services/src/Controller/WordController.php on line 27
Request URL: /Word/getWordCount
Client IP: 47.54.223.
Stack Trace:
#0 /home/mfeditin/public_html/mf_editing_services/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/home/mfeditin/...')
#1 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('App\\Controller\\...')
#2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('App\\Controller\\...')
#3 /home/mfeditin/public_html/mf_editing_services/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Core/App.php(152): class_exists('App\\Controller\\...')
#4 /home/mfeditin/public_html/mf_editing_services/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Core/App.php(64): Cake\Core\App::_classExistsInBase('\\Controller\\Wor...', 'App')
#5 /home/mfeditin/public_html/mf_editing_services/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ControllerFactory.php(68): Cake\Core\App::className('Word', 'Controller', 'Controller')
#6 /home/mfeditin/public_html/mf_editing_services/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php(90): Cake\Http\ControllerFactory->create(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#7 /home/mfeditin/public_html/mf_editing_services/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php(78): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#8 /home/mfeditin/public_html/mf_editing_services/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Http\BaseApplication->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#9 /home/mfeditin/public_html/mf_editing_services/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php(59): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#10 /home/mfeditin/public_html/mf_editing_services/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#11 /home/mfeditin/public_html/mf_editing_services/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php(88): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#12 /home/mfeditin/public_html/mf_editing_services/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#13 /home/mfeditin/public_html/mf_editing_services/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php(92): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#14 /home/mfeditin/public_html/mf_editing_services/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#15 /home/mfeditin/public_html/mf_editing_services/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(51): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#16 /home/mfeditin/public_html/mf_editing_services/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php(80): Cake\Http\Runner->run(Object(Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue), Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#17 /home/mfeditin/public_html/mf_editing_services/webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Http\Server->run()
#18 {main}
```

I am having an issue with using one of my vendor classes in my controller.

Basically, my code works great on localhost, but when I push it up to the production server, it renders a 500 error with the following message.

My controller code is as follows

```
use App\Controller\AppController; 
use App\Form\ContactForm; 
use Vendor\autoload; 

class WordController extends AppController 
{
    public function initialize() 
    { 
        parent::initialize(); 
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler'); 
    } 

    public function getWordCount() 
    { 
        if ($data = $this->request->data) 
        { 
            $wrap = new \Enzim\Lib\TikaWrapper\TikaWrapper; 

            $count = new \Enzim\Lib\TikaWrapper\TikaWrapper::getWordCount($data['file-0']['tmp_name']); 

            $count = 1; 

            $this->set('count', $count); 
            $this->set(compact('count')); 
        } else { 
            $this->Flash->error('We were unable to charge this card'); 
        }
    } 
}
```

If more information is required about either the production server, dependecies or anything else, please let me know.

Also; I should stress again, that this code works fine on localhost; and that it breaks where

```
$count = new \Enzim\Lib\TikaWrapper\TikaWrapper::getWordCount($data['file-0']['tmp_name']);
```

if I comment that above text, the controller runs, but of course, count is displayed as 1 (temporary placeholder to see that the ajax request is working..)

Comment: Thanks for the edit @T-Heron, I was literally doing the same thing as you, but you beat me to it, I am very inept with these <code> blocks.

Comment: You'll get used to it in short order...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP! Also show/describe the corresponding context, ie show/highlight the code that actually triggers the error, and please always mention your _exact_ (x.x.x) CakePHP version - thanks! Often problems even solve themselves when collecting these information.

Comment: That being said... how's that valid logic in the first place? I would assume `TikaWrapper:getWordCount()` to return a numeric value, instantiating something from it (ie passing it to `new`) surely wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi, I will update my post to fit your suggestions, thank you so much!

Also, adding or removing new before /Enzim doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not very readable, and it's still lacking the exact error message, hence the suggestion to copy it from the logs (`/logs/error.log`, `/logs/debug.log`) where it's way more readable and also includes the full error message, ie everything required in a copy & paste ready format.

Comment: Hi ndm, I updated the stack trace with the stack from the error.log 

Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: As you can see from the message, what you have there is a syntax error, your `new xyz::method()` syntax is invalid PHP, you cannot pass method calls to the `new` keyword, ie at this point this is a pure PHP problem (I'd suggest that you study the [**PHP OOP basics**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) a little bit). While it may still not work when removing the `new` keyword, I'm pretty sure that you won't receive the same error.

Comment: Hi, I started receiving a different error.

I need to install java on my production server to use the TikaWrapper. :)

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score -1):

If it works fine on localhost  , did you upload the .htaccess file?

Comment: Hi Ahmed, I have a working .htaccess file.

My entire site works, minus ONE page where this WordController is called.

Thanks for your quick answer!!